# Linux stock exchange trading software?

Tags: linux, software-rec

Linux is well known hackers box, but I am surprised I can't find a single tool for Linux to use stock exchange trading software (robot, automated rules, doing forex stuff).

Comment: There's also softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am surprised you didn't see

1. `Beantrader Latinum` in Ubuntu.
2. Google [[ forex ]](https://github.com/nick-orton/google-forex)
3. [[ These ]](http://www.linuxlinks.com/Software/Financial/Stockmarket/) in general.

---

<sup>Some of the packages in the link - [[ metatrader ]](http://www.metatrader4.com/en) being one - can be installed using [[ wine ]](https://www.winehq.org/) where as some others like
 [[ trading-shim ]](http://www.trading-shim.org/download/) need to be compiled from tarballs.</sup>

Comment: I cannot get how difficult is to google forex github

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : Great call, updated the answer :-)

Comment: My project in python https://github.com/folkien/pyStock